# How to get rid of "Click here to enter text" for literal content control with xml generated from serializer

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

This issue occurs when you have your content control mapped to xml that doesnt have closing tag. For eg. if the xml is and is mapped to literal control than on mapping the text displayed on word document(enable editing or printing) with be something like this

Click here to enter text even if you have removed the text when you create the content control. But if i change xml to than it works fine and i dont see any default text.

So the problem is that i have around 50-60 fields in the object that is serialized using xml serializer than by default it serializes to . So for entire document all the empty xml tags have default text displayed in word document.

Is this a known issue or am i missing something on my end? Is there a way is tweak generated xml to explicitly have closing tag?

This is very easy to recreate. I am using xml sdk v 2.0 and word 2010.

Regards

Mac

Edit Note:
**I am still facing this issue. When the custom xml has  than it displays the text "Click here to enter text." If i have xml  than it works fine. The problem is i have override xml that will force to generate the end tags. But when i parse within xml document it again converts it to self closing tags.**

Is there a way to look through the empty content controls and remove it from the document using sdk 2.0?

Comment: This text is a standard placeholder text and isn't inside the contents part of the run. It's displayed when the run is empty. So when you delete it the run gets an empty string and so doesn't display the standard text. Then you link it to a CustomXML which is null the placeholder get's displayed again. Either remove the ContentControl when not used or change from this standardized text inside the XML.

Comment: 1) Please register 2) please don't repost questions.  If you don't get any answers, consider editing your question to make it more clear, offer a bounty (which you can do in a couple days) or narrow the scope of your question.  Thanks.